# Parameter 0 of constructor required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Hi I am working on spring boot and I have tried a lot of methods I keep getting this error but it did not happen and some code shows red can you help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6eau.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obDoO.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH9jS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure the entity manager with username, password, and host. hibernate need entitymanager to connect database. you can add the configuration like this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.username=root
```

Also you need

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId> // your db connector
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: tried but gave the same error again

Comment: could you give us your code or pom.xml for an explanation? Your image is not clear, I added some information for pom.xml

Comment: i threw away my xml file

Comment: You don’t need hibernate core spring already has default hibernate, show me your code? All operations making on jpa sometimes you need hibernate for custom functionality. Jpa is standard of orm, hibernate is implementation for jpa

Comment: eclips mark these codes in red

Answer (score 0):

```
public City(int id, String name, String countryCode, String district, int population) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.countryCode = countryCode;
    this.district = district;
    this.population = population;
}
public City() {}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getCountryCode() {
    return countryCode;
}
public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
    this.countryCode = countryCode;
}
public String getDistrict() {
    return district;
}
public void setDistrict(String district) {
    this.district = district;
}
public int getPopulation() {
    return population;
}
public void setPopulation(int population) {
    this.population = population;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
@Repository
```

public class HibernateCityDal implements ICityDal {

```
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
public HibernateCityDal(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}


@Override
@Transactional
public List<City> getAll() {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    List<City> cities = session.createQuery("from City",City.class).getResultList();
    return cities;
}


@Override
public void add(City city) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void update(City city) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void delete(City city) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

@Service
public class CityManager implements ICityService {

```
private ICityDal cityDal;

@Autowired
public CityManager(ICityDal cityDal) {
    this.cityDal = cityDal;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public List<City> getAll() {
    return this.cityDal.getAll();
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void add(City city) {

    
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void update(City city) {

    
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void delete(City city) {

    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
  @RestController
```

@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CityController {

```
private ICityService cityService;

@Autowired
public CityController(ICityService cityService) {
    this.cityService = cityService;
}
@GetMapping("/cities")
public List<City> get(){
    return cityService.getAll();
}
```

}